# c# deleting button on click event

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make shopping cart for restaurant menu. I've created chosen items from menu as buttons and now I'm trying to figure out how to delete them on click event.

```
public partial class Krepselis : Form
{
    private List<KrepselisClass> lis;
    public Krepselis(List<KrepselisClass> list)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.lis = list;
    }

    private void Krepselis_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach(KrepselisClass krepselis in lis)
        {
            Button krepselisButton = new Button();
            krepselisButton.Text = krepselis.GetPatiekaloPavadinimas();
            krepselisButton.Location = new Point(0, 50 * i);
            krepselisButton.Font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 14);
            krepselisButton.Size = new Size(150, 40);
            krepselisButton.Tag = krepselis;
            KrepselisPanel.Controls.Add(krepselisButton);
            krepselisButton.Click += KrepselisPanel_Click;
            i++;

        }


    }

    private void KrepselisPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void KrepselisPanel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Also I'm trying to delete it from list aswell on click any ideas on how to do that ?

Answer (score 2):

`sender` gives you the control that triggered the event. So from there you can directly remove it from the panel:

```
private void KrepselisPanel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    KrepselisPanel.Controls.Remove((Control)sender);
}
```

Comment: Yes it is the answer. but use "this" instead "KrepselisPanel" word.